# Run PHP Site on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to Wordpress so I apologize if this is a basic question.

I have a PHP based website that you would normally just deploy to a virtual server and then be able to access it at www.example.com/index.php.  I need to deploy this site to Wordpress instead and be able to access it the same way. I don't want to have to do any modifications in Wordpress like adding pages.

What is the best way for me to achieve this?

Comment: Wordpress is a php website as well, you cannot *deploy a website with Wordpress*. You can however have a website alongside Wordpress.

Comment: Can you explain how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

What you asking is not possible.

WordPress is a CMS (*Content Management System*), so you need to add content to it to get a "website" from it.

Depending on how advanced your PHP based website is, WordPress might not be the best option for you.

That being said, if your PHP based website is simple and have pages, post and forms and similar logic, you can re-create it with WordPress significantly easy.

The manual labour will be necessary, you cant simple convert "bespoke system" (your website) to WordPress.